# Android - set focus on EditText after Spinner selection

Tags: android, xml, focus, android-edittext, spinner

I have the following items displayed on the screen:

```
EditText Forename
Spinner gender selection (Male | Female)
EditText Email
```

When the application is first launched, I want the focus to be set on the Forename EditText. Then after "Male" or "Female" has been selected in the Spinner,
I want the focus to be set on the Email EditText that is located below the spinner.

I have used `setOnItemSelectedListener` to set the `requestFocus` on the email EditText, but the problem is that it automatically sets the focus on
this EditText whenever I launch the application. 
This happens because by default the spinner displays the first selection which in this case is "Male" and therefore it thinks
that a selection has already been made and sets the focus on the Email field.

I don't mind the first selection to be already selected in the spinner by default but if I could somehow override the `requestFocus` to be set on the 
Forename EditText initially that would be great.

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ForenameForm"
        android:layout_width="285dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:hint="@string/forenameHint"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </EditText>


   <Spinner  
        android:id="@+id/SpinnerGender" 
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:textSize="30sp" 
        android:layout_width="285dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:prompt="@string/spinnerGender"  
        android:entries="@array/genderList">

    </Spinner>

   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EmailForm"
        android:layout_width="285dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:hint="@string/emailHint"
        android:lines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="20sp" >
    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Activity class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText forename=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ForenameForm);
        forename.requestFocus();

        final EditText email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EmailForm);

        Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerGender);
        spinner.setFocusable(true);
        spinner.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);   


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                email.requestFocus();               
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }               
        });  
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this solution.

```
define a boolean flag and set it default false.

in oncreate set the focus of forname

in setOnItemSelectedListener 
     if flag is false then set flag true
     else focus email
```

So your code will be like

```
boolean flag = false;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText forename=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.ForenameForm);
        forename.requestFocus();

        final EditText email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EmailForm);

        Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerGender);
        spinner.setFocusable(true);
        spinner.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);   


        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
              // changes here
                if(flag == false)
                    flag = true;
                else 
                    email.requestFocus();               
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            }               
        });  
    }
```

Comment: that's perfect! Thank you for your help, StinePike

Comment: Is it really the Android way of handling `onItemSelected`? How can I start an activity with items not selected?