# Moving cursor to the next field

Tags: android, user-interface

[image]

How do I move the cursor to the next line? I have two spinners, then a title edit text box and then two edit text boxes in which I am setting the date using a date picker. When setting the date in the "To"-field, the cursor is moved back to the Title field. After selecting the date I want it move to the next field which is "Send By", but it keeps returning to the previous field which is title field. Can anybody help?

Comment: you can use sendByEditText.requestFocus(); on selection of date

Comment: Posssibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179545/android-set-focus-on-edittext-after-spinner-selection

Answer (score 1):

```
 android:nextFocusDown="@+id/.."  
 android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/.."    
 android:nextFocusRight="@+id/.."    
 android:nextFocusUp="@+id/.."
```

or

```
 Spinner spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.SpinnerGender);
spinner.setFocusable(true);
spinner.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);  

 spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {

            if(flag == false)
                flag = true;
            else 
                edtTitle.requestFocus();               
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }               
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call requestFocus() on the corresponding EditText in the DatePicker.OnDateChangedListener method.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add this line to xml file Spinner/EditText Control..

android:imeOptions="actionNext"

or

android:imeOptions="actionNext"

android:singleLine="true"

Hope, this might help you..